# react ref implementation doesn't work on codesandbox but works on local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, codesandbox, react-ref

**Scenario**

I've created demo application using React, D3 and ref, it works perfectly fine on my local machine but it's not working when I do same on codesandbox.

**Codesandbox link**

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hofstadter-lj9ms?file=/src/components/Floor.jsx

**Goal**

If I click on any polygon/room it should Highlight it, like this
[image]

Comment: You have to fix your Sandbox first. Just look at the console and solve the problems there

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Yes, I can see that and that's exact what my question is, why I'm only getting that on codesandbox and not on my local machine.